# How to avoid executor deadlock in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured two multi branch projects (from GitHub) on my Jenkins installation. Currently the executor count is four.

Sometimes when there are a lot of branches to build it ends up in a situation where all executors are waiting for free executors and nothing happens.

How do you usually avoid this? Of course one cannot configure a million executors on a single machine to be sure this never happens.

I have now four executors trying to build and all of them are waiting for each other:

```
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor
```

Another question is that how/why is this even possible? They haven't implemented any mechanisms to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of deadlock if there is only one agent with label "agent1".

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'agent1' }

    stages {
        stage('simple deadlock') {
            agent { label 'agent1' }
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend setting agent in every stage or setting agent only at global level and not to combine both approaches.

Comment: I have `agent any` at global level and also other agent set in every stage like in your example. Is that bad? :)

Comment: It's not bad, but this is not optimal. Jenkins will reserve one "global" agent for any build of this pipeline and try to "allocate" another agent for stage. If you run as many build as there are agents available, then all agents will be blocked and no stage will be completed.
Try using `agent none` at global level if every stage in pipeline has it's own agent.

Comment: Ok, setting the global agent to `none` seems to ultimately solve the issue.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56241901/7919597